# Change data.frame into array

Tags: r

Here is my code,is there more simple way to change iris into array ?
Requirements:when you changed it ,d[2,3]=iris[2,3]=1.4

```
data(iris)
r=nrow(iris)
c=ncol(iris)
d=array(0,dim=c(r,c))
for (i in 1:r){
  for (j in 1:c){
      d[i,j]=iris[i,j]}}
```

Comment: This is your third question on a very similar theme, If you were to give a better explanation of what you are trying to do (eg why you want your data in an array, not a data.frame) then perhaps help would be more readily offered.

Comment: All entries in an array must be the same type. But the last column of `iris` is a factor. Here are some (possibly useful) ideas to try: `as.matrix(iris)`, `as.matrix(iris[, -5])`, `data.matrix(iris)`.

Comment: i want to know R better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a really unusual thing to do.

**No, it's worse than unusual.  It's probably just bad. Matrices and arrays are useful, appropriate and very fast if all of the data is of a single class.  If you have mixed classes, then work with data frames instead.**

But here you go. In the first example all of your data is converted to `character`, in the second to `numeric`.

```
x <- as.array(as.matrix(iris))

head(x)
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species 
[1,] "5.1"        "3.5"       "1.4"        "0.2"       "setosa"
[2,] "4.9"        "3.0"       "1.4"        "0.2"       "setosa"
[3,] "4.7"        "3.2"       "1.3"        "0.2"       "setosa"
[4,] "4.6"        "3.1"       "1.5"        "0.2"       "setosa"
[5,] "5.0"        "3.6"       "1.4"        "0.2"       "setosa"
[6,] "5.4"        "3.9"       "1.7"        "0.4"       "setosa"
```

Or...

```
x <- array(unlist(iris), dim=c(150, 5), dimnames=list(NULL, names(iris)))

head(x)
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
[1,]          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2       1
[2,]          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2       1
[3,]          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2       1
[4,]          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2       1
[5,]          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2       1
[6,]          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4       1
```

Comment: +1 for explaining why this is a bad idea *and* giving an answer